# Android outcoming call is taken listener

Tags: android

I need run method, when is outcoming call is taken. It is in Android possible?

I test BroadcastReceiver - PhoneStateListener, it work only on outcoming call start, not on outcoming call is taken.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `TelephonyManager`. It has the `PhoneStateListener` as you said in which you can listen for `PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged(int, String)`. In this method the states are three as listed in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String)).

> - CALL_STATE_IDLE
> - CALL_STATE_RINGING
> - CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK

The one you are looking for is `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` which is the state for:

> Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

Comment: I use PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged, but if outcoming call is taken (from recipient) onCallStateChanged is not called. Is any trick how detect it? I read calling log, but call is write to log when end.

Comment: That is a problem, I don't know another way to proceed